# GRUB error-can i format HDD and fix it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue, chromeos

I deleted my ubuntu partitions from windows XP
now when i start up it says grub error..
i do not have any important information on my pc(all backed up to cloud)
can i just format the whole thing and install a new OS [chrome probably], without worrying about this grub error?

again- i have no issue with formatting my pc [would be quite glad to do it]

up till now i was dual booting windows xp and ubuntu 13.04. now i would like to switch to chrome os

please help.
i need help ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special part of the drive called the "Master boot record".  This is where grub generally lives.  Installing a new os will automatically fix the issue.  Formatting the drive alone will not fix the issue.

As a more general answer.  The easiest way to fix Master boot record issues is to install a new os, or run the mbr.exe program on a windows recovery disk.